# How can I parse this particular JSON data from LastFM using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I'm attempting to parse a JSON feed using the [LastFM API](http://www.last.fm/api) but there are certain elements returned in the JSON array that are prefixed with a # that I don't know how to reference.

The feed URL is [here](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.getevents&api_key=ca1599876cde298491941da8577de666&format=json&callback=?) and it can be seen [visualised here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.getevents&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&format=json).

My jQuery code so far looks like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.getevents&api_key=ca1599876cde298491941da8577de666&format=json&callback=?', function(data) {

        $.each(data.events.event, function(i, item) {

            html += "<li><a class='fm-event' href='" + item.url + "'><h4>" + item.title + "</h4>";
            html += "<p>at " + item.venue.name + ", " + item.venue.location.city + "<br />";
            html += "on " + item.startDate + "</p>";
            html += "<img src='" + item.venue.image.text + "' />"; // This doesn't work. how do I do this?
            html += "</a></li>";
        });

        $("#last-fm-events").append(html);

    });
```

I'm basically looping through each item in the feed and dynamically building a list which is then appended to the DOM.

What I can't figure out is how to get at the URLs for the image items in the feed. There are different ones for different sizes. The JSON for the image elements looks like this:

```
"image": [
            {
              "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/34\/2243904.gif",
              "size": "small"
            },
            {
              "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/64\/2243904.gif",
              "size": "medium"
            },
            {
              "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/126\/2243904.gif",
              "size": "large"
            },
            {
              "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/252\/2243904.gif",
              "size": "extralarge"
            },
            {
              "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/_\/2243904\/A38.gif",
              "size": "mega"
            }
          ]
        }
```

But I don't understand why the text element in the array is prefixed with a # and how to get the URL for an image of a particular size. Any help appreciated as I'm a jQuery beginner! Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a very strange way for them to format the object (barring requirements I'm not aware of, which is *entirely* likely).

Basically, there are two ways to get at the property of an object in JavaScript: Using a literal for the name (e.g., `obj.propertyName`), as you have, or using a string with brackets notation (e.g., `obj["propertyName"]`). Sometimes you *have* to use the string approach, if the literal would be an invalid identifier in JavaScript (and `#text` would be) or if you're creating the property name on the fly. So to get `item.venue.image.#text` (which would be invalid), you'd use `item.venue.image["#text"]` instead.

**But**, what you've shown us for `image` is an array where each *element* has a `#text` property, not where the array itself does. If you want to find the URL for a given size, unfortunately you have to search through the array for it:

```
function findUrl(image, size) {
    var n, entry;

    for (n = 0; n < image.length; ++n) {
        // Get this entry from the array
        entry = image[n];

        // Is this the size we want?
        if (entry.size == size) {  // (`size` is a valid identifier, can use a literal)
            // Yes, return this URL
            return entry["#text"]; // (`#text` is not, must use brackets and a string)
        }
    }
    return null; // Or "" or undefined or whatever you want to use for "not found"
}
```

Using it where you're having trouble:

```
html += "<img src='" + findUrl(item.venue.image, "medium") + "' />";
```

...assuming you want the "medium" URL.

Of course, if the API documentation guarantees that certain sizes will be at certain indexes, you don't need to go searching, you could just index into the array directly. For instance, in the example you showed us, the "medium" URL entry is at position 1 in the array. If that's guaranteed, you don't have to search:

```
html += "<img src='" + item.venue.image[1]["#text"] + "' />";
```

...which says "give me the '#text' property of the object at index 1 in the array." (Well, essentially. In fact, JavaScript arrays aren't really arrays, but let's not go into it here...)

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer which helps me understand a bit more about JSON. I'm also glad you too find it a slightly weird way to return data - I wasn't sure if I was missing something obvious! Anyway, your solution works perfectly and I'm very grateful.

Comment: @Dan Diplo: Excellent, glad that helped. Yeah, the more usual JSON and JavaScript way would be: `{"image": {"small": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/34\/2243904.gif", "medium": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/64\/2243904.gif", ... }}` But they're probably creating this on-the-fly from a different source format (XML, from the looks of it).

Comment: Thanks so much!  Helped me greatly with that confusing #text element.

Comment: Lifesaver! I was confused with the #text element and I needed the artist image. Great work!